# SQL Server import export assistant error when importing time type

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion, sqldatatypes, sql-import-wizard

I'm trying to import a table from a txt file comma separated, the file was generated by the same SQL Server import/export assistant from my development database server.

Many tables has been imported by this way successfully.

The problem is when I have a column of the type date.

The message is: conversion unknown!

And then I cannot exec the package.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you change type in mappings?

Comment: nop I didn't change the type in mapping

Comment: Ok, I tryed with DT_DATE, DT_DBDATE, DT_DBTIME, DT_DBTIME2 and the message is "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data"

Comment: can you narrow your problem and upload somewhere the file?